# Can I run WSGI server with gunicorn without python web frameworks in a resource-constrained environment?

Tags: python, gunicorn, wsgi

I know it's a bit absurd to ask, but can I avoid using web frameworks like - `Flask`, `Falcon`, etc and run bare-minimal WSGI server in an `nginx` environment. I am trying to run my WSGI process in a tight and highly-resource-constrained environment - something like Raspberry Pi. I will not be requiring to handle much of the client load. The number of clients will be 1 or 2 at max. No more than 10 queries per second. So just wondering if I can knock out every component possible by writing some Python code myself.

I have been searching for any documentation on this, but couldn't get much info. Any pointers or suggestions to serve custom python web application without a full-fledged framework is welcome. Last resort would be to understand [falcon](https://github.com/falconry/falcon/tree/master/falcon) source code and write a minimal API code myself, which I have already started.

Comment: and I have at most only one route to be added to the web app.

Comment: Sure you can. I recommend you reading [this](https://ruslanspivak.com/lsbaws-part1/) tutorial series. It explains how WSGI and web frameworks work together.